# How to show bank balance through transactions in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-controller, laravel-models

I have Bank table and transaction table. The relationship is one-to-many, so a bank may have many transactions. Transaction table has the bank foreign key(bank_id). and each transaction has a column 'type' which is either credit or debit.
I want to show each bank balance based on its transactions.

Here are my questions:

1. How to select a specific bank?
2. How to calculate the balance for a bank?
3. Should I calculate it in controller, model, or view? which one is the best?

Here is transactions table:
[image]
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You'd select a bank like

```
$bank = Bank::find(2);
```

and you could do something like

```
$bank->transactions->sum('amount');
```

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to show the balance of each bank in my database. I had to sum all credits which belongs to a bank and then sum all debits for that bank and then find the balance, which is credits minus debits. So using relationship you mentioned. I wrote this code.   
<td>{{$bank->transactions->where('type', 'credit')->sum('amount') - $bank->transactions->where('type', 'debit')->sum('amount')}}</td>

Answer (score 1):

You need to create relationships in the model, like this in the Transactions model:

```
public function bank(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class);
}
```

and this in the Bank Model

```
public function transactions (){
 return $this->hasMany(Transactions::class);
}
```

Then you can access them like this:

```
$this->bank->transactions;
```

Laravel has excellent docs, you just need to read them, e.g. [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: thanks @damask for your quick response. I have done the relationship between bank and transaction. but now I got stuck that how to choose a specific bank and then show it's balance. can you help with that?

Comment: thanks @damask! I got the idea from your code and the problem solved.

Comment: @MahdiJafari You should accept an Answer, or explain how you solved your problem to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show the balance of each bank in my database. I had to sum all credits which belongs to a bank and then sum all debits for that bank and then find the balance, which is credits minus debits. So using relationship you mentioned. I wrote this code.

```
<td>{{$bank->transactions->where('type', 'credit')->sum('amount') - $bank->transactions->where('type', 'debit')->sum('amount')}}</td>
```